# vyos, wan load balancing with one static and one pppoe connection

Tags: wan, load-balancing, vyatta, vyos

I have two ISPs, one static and one PPPoE. I use VyOS.

I did the configuration with two static IP providers but when it comes to PPPoE I don't know what to write as the next hop for the interface health.

```
interface-health pppoe0 {
        failure-count 1
        nexthop ???
        success-count 1
        test 10 {
            resp-time 5
            target 8.8.8.8
            ttl-limit 1
            type ping
        }
    }
```

Is the next hop of a PPPoE connection always the same or it can change once disconnected and connected again?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to define an egress interface rather than an IP address as the next hop?

Comment: No, as far as I know. Only a ping test through the next hop and a ttl test with an UDP packet also through the next hop

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can set next-hop as dhcp

```
set load-balancing wan interface-health pppoe1 nexthop dhcp
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help:

```
load-balancing {
    wan {
        flush-connections
        interface-health eth1 {
            failure-count 3
            nexthop <gatewayip>
            success-count 1
            test 10 {
                resp-time 5
                target 8.8.8.8
                ttl-limit 1
                type ping
            }
            test 20 {
                resp-time 5
                target 8.8.4.4
                ttl-limit 1
                type ping
            }
        }
        interface-health pppoe0 {
            failure-count 3
            nexthop <gatewayip>
            success-count 1
            test 10 {
                resp-time 5
                target <nameserverip>
                ttl-limit 1
                type ping
            }
            test 20 {
                resp-time 5
                target <nameserverip>
                ttl-limit 1
                type ping
            }
        }
```